# Resource limitations on php curl

Tags: php, curl

I have a page where I retrieve content from many urls with curl.  I found that after a certain number of urls retrieved, curl returns null.  Is there a limit on the resources that curl will retrieve in any given session.

I do a `curl_init()` before retrieving each url and a `curl_close()` after getting the content.  I thought that this would free resources right away would prevent a situation of reaching limits.  Are there issues with calling `curl_init()` too  many times.

Here is a sample of the php code where I retrieve the urls.

```
<?php
    function get_curl() {
        // Initialize a new curl resource
        $ch = curl_init(); 

        // Get only the content not the headers
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 

        // Return the value instead of printing the response to browser
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

        // Use a user agent to mimic a browser
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.7.5) Gecko/20041107 Firefox/1.0');

        return $ch;

        // Remember to always close the session and free all resources 
    }

    // Make sure curl is installed
    $curl_exists = function_exists('curl_init');
    if ( !$curl_exists ) {
        return;
    }

    $todayfeast = date("Ymd");

    $ctitleff = 'http://feed.evangelizo.org/reader.php?date='.$todayfeast.'&type=reading_lt&lang=FR&content=FR';
    $creadff = 'http://feed.evangelizo.org/reader.php?date='.$todayfeast.'&type=reading&lang=FR&content=FR';

    $ch = get_curl();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $ctitleff);        
    $titleff = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch); 

    $ch = get_curl();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $creadff);      
    $readff = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $ctitlepf = 'http://feed.evangelizo.org/reader.php?date='.$todayfeast.'&type=reading_lt&lang=FR&content=PS';
    $creadpf = 'http://feed.evangelizo.org/reader.php?date='.$todayfeast.'&&type=reading&lang=FR&content=PS';

    $ch = get_curl();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $ctitlepf);    
    $titlepf = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch); 

    $ch = get_curl();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $creadpf); 
    $readpf = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $titlesf = 'http://feed.evangelizo.org/reader.php?date='.$todayfeast.'&type=reading_lt&lang=FR&content=SR';
    $readsf = 'http://feed.evangelizo.org/reader.php?date='.$todayfeast.'&type=reading&lang=FR&content=SR';

    $ch = get_curl();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $titlesf);  
    $titlesf = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch); 

    $ch = get_curl();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $readsf); 
    $readsf = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $titlegf = 'http://feed.evangelizo.org/reader.php?date='.$todayfeast.'&type=reading_lt&lang=FR&content=GSP';
    $readgf = 'http://feed.evangelizo.org/reader.php?date='.$todayfeast.'&type=reading&lang=FR&content=GSP';

    $ch = get_curl();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $titlegf); 
    $titlegf = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch); 

    $ch = get_curl();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $readgf); 
    $readgf = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch); 

    // Send info
    $params = array(
        'titleff' => $titleff,
        'readff' => $readff,
        'titlepf' => $titlepf,
        'readpf' => $readpf,
        'titlesf' => $titlesf,
        'readsf' => $readsf,
        'titlegf' => $titlegf,
        'readgf' => $readgf,
    );

    echo json_encode($params);

?>
```

**EDIT**

The problem only happens when I call this php script through ajax.

```
<script>
    $('#readingf').ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "loadfrench.php",
        type: "GET",
        data: { },
        cache: false,
        async: true,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
            if (response != '') 
            {
            $('#titleff').html(response.titleff);
            $('#readff').html(response.readff);
            $('#titlepf').html(response.titlepf);
            $('#readpf').html(response.readpf);
            $('#titlesf').html(response.titlesf);
            $('#readsf').html(response.readsf);
            $('#titlegf').html(response.titlegf);
            $('#readgf').html(response.readgf);
            alert ('titleff '+response.titleff+' readff '+response.readff);
            }
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
            alert ("status "+status+" error "+error+"responseText "+request.responseText);
        },
    });    

    });
</script>
```

If I have this file instead, and include in my main page with `<?php require("filename.php") ?>` it works.

```
<?php
    function get_curl() {
        // Initialize a new curl resource
        $ch = curl_init(); 

        // Get only the content not the headers
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 

        // Return the value instead of printing the response to browser
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

        // Use a user agent to mimic a browser
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.7.5) Gecko/20041107 Firefox/1.0');

        return $ch;

        // Remember to always close the session and free all resources 
    }

    // Make sure curl is installed
    $curl_exists = function_exists('curl_init');
    if ( !$curl_exists ) {
        return;
    }

    $ch = get_curl();

    $todayfeast = date("Ymd");
    /* $titleff = $readff = $titlepf = $readpf = $titlesf = $readsf = $titlegf = $readgf = "blank"; */

    $ctitleff = 'http://feed.evangelizo.org/reader.php?date='.$todayfeast.'&type=reading_lt&lang=FR&content=FR';
    $creadff = 'http://feed.evangelizo.org/reader.php?date='.$todayfeast.'&type=reading&lang=FR&content=FR';

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $ctitleff);        
    $titleff = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $creadff);      
    $readff = curl_exec($ch);

    $ctitlepf = 'http://feed.evangelizo.org/reader.php?date='.$todayfeast.'&type=reading_lt&lang=FR&content=PS';
    $creadpf = 'http://feed.evangelizo.org/reader.php?date='.$todayfeast.'&&type=reading&lang=FR&content=PS';

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $ctitlepf);    
    $titlepf = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $creadpf); 
    $readpf = curl_exec($ch);

    $titlesf = 'http://feed.evangelizo.org/reader.php?date='.$todayfeast.'&type=reading_lt&lang=FR&content=SR';
    $readsf = 'http://feed.evangelizo.org/reader.php?date='.$todayfeast.'&type=reading&lang=FR&content=SR';

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $titlesf);  
    $titlesf = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $readsf); 
    $readsf = curl_exec($ch);

    $titlegf = 'http://feed.evangelizo.org/reader.php?date='.$todayfeast.'&type=reading_lt&lang=FR&content=GSP';
    $readgf = 'http://feed.evangelizo.org/reader.php?date='.$todayfeast.'&type=reading&lang=FR&content=GSP';

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $titlegf); 
    $titlegf = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $readgf); 
    $readgf = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch); 

    // Send info
    $params = array(
        'titleff' => $titleff,
        'readff' => $readff,
        'titlepf' => $titlepf,
        'readpf' => $readpf,
        'titlesf' => $titlesf,
        'readsf' => $readsf,
        'titlegf' => $titlegf,
        'readgf' => $readgf,
    );

    echo json_encode($params);

?>


<?php
    $curl_exists = function_exists('curl_init');

    // Make sure curl is installed
    if ( $curl_exists ) {

        // Initialize a new curl resource
        $ch = curl_init(); 

        // Get only the content not the headers
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 

        // Return the value instead of printing the response to browser
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

        // Use a user agent to mimic a browser
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.7.5) Gecko/20041107 Firefox/1.0');

    }

?>

<div id="readfre" style="overflow:hidden;">
<div id="readingf" class="tabber" style="width:100%; margin-top: 10px; margin-right:0px;">

<?php 

    $todayfeast = date("Ymd");

    $ctitleff = 'http://feed.evangelizo.org/reader.php?date='.$todayfeast.'&type=reading_lt&lang=FR&content=FR';
    $creadff = 'http://feed.evangelizo.org/reader.php?date='.$todayfeast.'&type=reading&lang=FR&content=FR';

    if ( $curl_exists ) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $ctitleff);        
        $titleff = curl_exec($ch);
    }

    if ( $curl_exists ) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $creadff);      
        $readff = curl_exec($ch);
    }

?>
    <div id="readf" class="tabbertab">
        <h2>PremiËre Lecture</h2>
        <div id='titleff' class='rtitle'>
        <?php echo $titleff; ?>
        </div>
        <div id='readff' class='rtext'>
        <?php echo $readff; ?>
        </div>
    </div>

<?php

    $ctitlepf = 'http://feed.evangelizo.org/reader.php?date='.$todayfeast.'&type=reading_lt&lang=FR&content=PS';
    $creadpf = 'http://feed.evangelizo.org/reader.php?date='.$todayfeast.'&&type=reading&lang=FR&content=PS';

    if ( $curl_exists ) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $ctitlepf);    
        $titlepf = curl_exec($ch);
    }

    if ( $curl_exists ) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $creadpf); 
        $readpf = curl_exec($ch);
    }
?>  
    <div id="readp" class="tabbertab">
        <h2>Psaume</h2>
        <div id='titlepf' class='rtitle'>
        <?php echo $titlepf; ?>
        </div>
        <div id='readpf' class='rtext'>
        <?php echo $readpf; ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php

        $titlesf = 'http://feed.evangelizo.org/reader.php?date='.$todayfeast.'&type=reading_lt&lang=FR&content=SR';
        $readsf = 'http://feed.evangelizo.org/reader.php?date='.$todayfeast.'&type=reading&lang=FR&content=SR';

        if ( $curl_exists ) {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $titlesf);  
            $titlesf = curl_exec($ch);
        }

        if ( $curl_exists ) {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $readsf); 
            $readsf = curl_exec($ch);
        }

    ?>
        <div id="reads" class="tabbertab">
            <h2>DeuxiËme Lecture</h2>
            <div id='titlesf' class='rtitle'>
            <?php echo $titlesf; ?>
            </div>
            <div id='readsf' class='rtext'>
            <?php echo $readsf; ?>
            </div>
        </div>

    <?php

        $titlegf = 'http://feed.evangelizo.org/reader.php?date='.$todayfeast.'&type=reading_lt&lang=FR&content=GSP';
        $readgf = 'http://feed.evangelizo.org/reader.php?date='.$todayfeast.'&type=reading&lang=FR&content=GSP';

        if ( $curl_exists ) {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $titlegf); 
            $titlegf = curl_exec($ch);
        }

        if ( $curl_exists ) {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $readgf); 
            $readgf = curl_exec($ch);
        }

    ?>
        <div id="readg" class="tabbertab">
            <h2>Evangile</h2>
            <div id='titlegf' class='rtitle'>
            <?php echo $titlegf; ?>
            </div>
            <div id='readgf' class='rtext'>
            <?php echo $readgf; ?>
            </div>
        </div>

    <?php

        // Remember to always close the session and free all resources 
        if ( $curl_exists ) {
            curl_close($ch); 
        } 
    ?>

    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Have you looked at multi-curl? It will speed the downloading process up quite a bit and it might solve your problem.

Comment: Please take a look at [`curl_multi_exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php), it will make your script so much faster. Regarding `I thought that this would free resources right away` - this is rarely the case for anything in PHP, [read this](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/features.gc.php)

Comment: "after a certain number of urls retrieved, curl returns null." - Is this the same number every time? (i.e. is it the same url causing an error). Have you tried each curl request individually to ensure that they are all working in isolation?

Comment: @DaveRandom @Ing @Los Frijoles  Strangely enough this problem only happens if I call the php script through ajax. If instead I call curl in a php file loaded directly with `<?php require("filename.php"); ?>` all the content is retrieved. Does ajax interfere with curl?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot say exactly why it happens, but seeing you are fetching from the same server, I would not create a new curl handle every time. Simply use the same and only change CURLOPT_URL. That way, the server will reuse the TCP connection, instead of creating a new one every time:

```
$ch = get_curl();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $ctitleff);        
$titleff = curl_exec($ch);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $creadff);      
$readff = curl_exec($ch);

...

curl_close($ch);
```

Not sure it's an answer, but it's something to try :)

Also, you might want to take a look at [curl-multi-exec()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php)